# Manually encrypting Firefox's key3.db in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, firefox, encryption

I am a person who tends to leave personal items behind when I leave a cafe or library or restaurant. I've lost my laptop a number of times now and thankfully had it returned, but it's only a matter of time until someone doesn't...

I would like to make my Firefox passwords safe from identity theft in the situation where a hacker has physical access to my laptop.

However, I don't want to use Firefox's built-in master password encryption as it is incredibly annoying to use (pops up and grabs focus while I'm typing in the address bar, asks for passwords multiple times, etc).

I'm also unable to encrypt my entire hard drive as my computer is old and doesn't have hardware support for this.

I would simply like to use Windows to encrypt Firefox's key3.db file. It should be automatically decrypted by Windows when I type in my Windows password at boot / wake from sleep. So, if the machine goes to sleep or is turned off, the file will be encrypted on the disc. Can Windows 10 do this and what is the best approach to take?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest solution would be to use the free and open-source
[VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html),
to move your Firefox profile to a VeraCrypt container.

See the
[Beginner's Tutorial](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Beginner's%20Tutorial.html),
section "How to Create and Use a VeraCrypt Container" for instructions on
creating a VeraCrypt volume residing in a file, also called container,
and which can be mounted with a disk letter.

This VeraCrypt volume can be defined as a
[Favorite Volume](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Favorite%20Volumes.html),
which is automatically mounted when you log on to Windows. See the link for
instructions.

When working with encrypted data, one should always anticipate a glitch which
renders the data unusable. Regular backups are highly recommended.